# Compatibility between MongoDB server and Mongo C++ Driver

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm new to the MongoDB. My virtual machine runs Ubuntu 14.04.5 with `mongod`, which is standard for this OS:

```
hekto@ubuntu:~$ mongod --version
db version v2.4.9
Tue Jun  5 18:00:23.923 git version: nogitversion
```

I've built a Mongo C++ Driver Ver 3.2.0 from sources and tried to write some tests. All of them output an exception below:

```
Server at localhost:27017 reports wire version 0, but this version of libmongoc requires at least 3 (MongoDB 3.0): generic server error
```

It looks like the C++ client and the server are incompatible.

Are there any tricks, which can be used with the Mongo C++ Driver to force it to work with older Mongo servers?

I can't convert the database itself to any new format for now, but also wouldn't like to learn the obsolete driver API.

Comment: FYI Older library releases which are compatible with pre MongoDB 3.0 releases also use MONGODB-CR for authentication. The upcoming MongoDB 4.0 release will remove support for this completely. If you want to support older servers, then you're on your own to create wrappers around the libraries. Noting your comment below, please don't turn this into a "how do I upgrade", because that question is separate and already answered as well as being "off-topic" as a non-programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB 2.4.9 has been end-of-life for quite some time: https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy, and most drivers have dropped support for talking to it.

If you are just starting with MongoDB, you should start with the newest available stable version, which is currently 3.6.5.

You can obtain packages for Ubuntu 14.04 according to the instructions here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I've tried to do exactly that and got into problems with database format. Is it any straightforward way to convert the existing database to the currently supported format?

Comment: @HEKTO  Upgrading can be challenging, and isn't my area of expertise. One idea though would be to leverage replication. I recommend asking a specific question about how you can upgrade from 2.4 to 3.6. It is much easier if you can accept downtime. But as I said, not an area I'm very knowledgeable about. That said, MongoDB 3.6 is a radically superior product to 2.4 and you should do whatever it takes to get off 2.4